# In which Doctor Who story does the Doctor become the Time Lord Victorious and allow Wilfred to die?

Tags: story-identification, doctor-who

I know that in one timeline, the Tenth Doctor became Time Lord Victorious and left Wilfred to die, after which he become an emperor.

But what episode/audio/comics is this story told in? Where can I find out the full story and in what order should I discover materials about this timeline?

Comment: I presume you're referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Lord_Victorious)?

Comment: I don't really know, but i will look this link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't read it myself but I believe you are referring to the Four Doctors

Taken from the [synopsis from the wiki](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Four_Doctors_(comic_story)) (emphasis by me)

> The group materialises as ghosts in a different point of the Doctor's timeline. Specifically, they are in the Tenth Doctor's timeline, at the Naismith mansion. The six watch another Tenth Doctor **let Wilfred Mott die** in the glass chamber, stating that of the two of them, he is more important to the universe and must continue living.

> In it, the alternate Tenth Doctor has now fully succumbed to his darker impulses and has become the **Time Lord Victorious**, a tyrant who rules over the universe.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're talking about two different episodes, or perhaps not quite remembering it correctly.

The Doctor declared himself the Time Lord Victorious during [The Waters of Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Waters_of_Mars) after deciding that

> The laws of time are mine, and they will obey me!

However, I do not believe The Doctor ever left [Wilfred Mott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfred_Mott) to die. There was a moment's hesitation when Wilf got himself into trouble during [The End of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Time_(Doctor_Who)) where Wilf.

> Sealed himself into a lethal chamber.

and

> The 10th Doctor swapped places with him, sacrificing his own regeneration to save Wilf's life.

Comment: Nah, there is timeline where doctor left him.

Comment: https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Lord_Victorious

Comment: In an alternate timeline envisioned by a Dalek continuity bomb, rather than exposing himself to lethal radiation to rescue Wilfred Mott at Joshua Naismith's mansion, the Tenth Doctor judged himself to be more important to live and let Wilf die. He reclaimed the "Time Lord Victorious" title and became emperor of the universe, demanding tributes from ambassadors from across the universe to help feed the starving. He was ultimately assassinated by a Raxacoricofallapatorian.

Comment: `Raxacoricofallapatorian` would be an excellent password, if only one could memorize how to spell it properly. _Braces for 10,000 failed attempts to log into my SE account..._